# FLink Application - interface to MySql and MongoDb

Tags: mysql, scala, intellij-idea

*This post is marked for **deletion**, as the issue was with the IDE in not creating the proper jar, hence issues with the code interaction*

---

I have a small flink application that reads from a kafka topic,
needs to query if the input from the topic (x) exists in a column of MySql Database before processing it (Not Ideal but its the current requirement)

When I run the Application through the ***IDE (Intellij) -> It works***.
However when I submit the job to ***flink server it fails*** to open connection based on driver

**Error from Flink Server**

```
// ERROR
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)

// ---------------------
// small summary of MAIN
// ---------------------
Get Data from Source (x)
source.map(x => {
  // open connection (Fails to open)
  // check if data exist in db
})


// -------------------------------------
// open connection function (Scala Code)
// -------------------------------------
def openConnection() : Boolean = {

try {
  // - set driver
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  // - make the connection
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pswd)
  // - set status controller
  connection_open = true
}
catch {
  // - catch error
  case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace
  // - set status controller
  connection_open = false
}

// return result
return connection_open
}
```

**Question**

1) Whats the correct way to interface to MySql Database from a flink application?

2) I will also at a later stage have to do similar interaction with MongoDB, whats the correct way interacting with MongoDB from FLink?

Answer (score 1):

> Unbelievable IntelliJ does not update dependencies on rebuild command.

In IntelliJ, You have to delete and re-setup your artifact creator for all dependencies do be added. (Build, Clean, Rebuild,Delete) does not update its settings.

I deleted and recreated the artifact file. And it Works
Apologies for the unnecessary inconvenience (As you can imagine my frustration). But it's a word of caution for those developing in IntelliJ, to manually delete and recreate artifacts

**Solution:**
 (File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> (-) delete previous one -> (+) create new one -> Select Main Class)